Rules for pronouncing a syllable with multiple IPA phonemes
I'm trying to get the IPA notation for each new French word i learn. I have also learnt how to pronounce each phoneme individually, for example, /e/, /ʒ/, /ʁ/ etc.
The problem is that learning the IPA is not enough since each syllable can have more than 1 phoneme, for example, the IPA for réveille is /ʁe.vɛj/. naturally the question arises: how to pronounce, say, /ʁe/, where should I stress? What are the rules? Are there rules?
The furthest I can gather on the internet are vowels cluster such as eu, oi as diphthongs, but the list is very limited.
I would appreciate any pointers, thanks.

I don't understand your question. You say you don't know where to put the stress in /ʁe/; here, /ʁ/ is a consonant, and /e/ is a vowel. In French, as in most languages, the stress always falls on vowels.

@PeterShor Yes, I first understood that part like you but I believe Lauren is asking which one of the syllables to stress.

@jlliagre: Yes, that seems likely.

Sorry guys, i'm asking what are the rules for pronouncing two or more phonemes combined in one syllable, @PeterShor you mentioned about always stressing on vowels, is there a name for this rule? are there more rules like this?

I know how to pronounce /ʁ/, and /e/ individually, but how to know if i'm pronouncing /ʁe/ right? like what are the rules and constraints?

I believe you can't pronounce a consonant without a vowel.

Or at least, it's much harder to pronounce consonants without any vowel before or after. Sure you can say mmmm but there will probably be a schwa.

You pronounce /ʁe/ like this.

I suspect this is a consequence of your IPA learning material pronouncing the consonants with an accompanying vowel. Otherwise it's hard to understand your problem. But you know how to pronounce the Englilsh word "ray", right? In IPA, that is /re:/ -- the /r/ has no accompanying vowel. It's the same with /ʁe/.

@TonyK English pronunciation is usually reported as /ɹeɪ/ but you got the idea. Such a confusion could indeed explain the issue.

What do you mean by "stress"? There's virtually no stress in French, but even if there was, there's only one way to stress a one-syllable word, isn't it?

Please try to punctuate correctly. Otherwise, this seems like text messaging. By stress, you mean tonic accent, right? In French, it's always the last syllable.

https://www.thoughtco.com/esl-intonation-stress-types-1212091  Tonic stress refers to the syllable in a word which receives the most stress in an intonation unit

The stress in not shown for words represented in French IPA because:

The last syllable of an isolated single word got the stress, always. No exception.

When multiple words are uttered, i.e. in regular sentences, the stress, if any, only appears on the last syllable of rhythmic groups.

The stress is often light but there can be significant variations, especially with regional accents.


See: Intonation and
How to determine rhythmic groups
Syllables indeed have more than one phoneme. There are no specific rule on how to join phonemes to make syllables in French. The stress is always on the vowel (thanks @PeterShor, I didn't even thought a consonant could be stressed). Stress never affects the value of a vowel, unlike English.
See: La syllabe phonétique

does it mean that, for example, "euros" /øʁo/, it will be pronounced like uh-oo, and the consonant in between can be skipped? if i have to make the uvular fricative, it will be very very different than just uh-oo, correct me if i'm wrong please.

Euros is pronounced /ø.ʁo/. The French R is starting the second syllable and of course needs to be pronounced. Why would you want to drop it?

You might be using stress to name something different than what it means in phonology.
